# Combinatoric meaning of critical points of a generating function

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions

In Fiore and Leinster's [Objects of Categories as Complex Numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212377), there's a notion of "high zero".  For example, the set of triples of binary trees plus an extra point is a "high zero": in their model, the set $T$ of binary trees comes equipped with the isomorphism $$T \cong T^2 + 1,$$ (a binary tree is either a node with two subtrees or it's a leaf) so it can be thought of as having a cardinality that's a primitive sixth root of 1. Three binary trees have cardinality -1 and adding an extra point gives cardinality 0.

Derivatives of data types give rise to the notion of a "[zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29)", a data structure with a "hole" in it.  Flajolet and Sedgewick in section VIII of their *Analytic Combinatorics* show how saddle points let you prove upper & lower bounds on the growth of the coefficients of a generating function, but the existence of zippers suggests to me that the zeros and critical points of a generating function should be counting something.

One can use Newton's method in the form
$$x_{n+1} = x_n + f(x_n)\frac{1}{1-(f'(x_n) + 1)}$$
to define a series of data structures converging on a data structure $x$ such that $f(x)$ is a high zero (where $\frac{1}{1-x}$ indicates a list of $x$s).  But it's not clear to me what the combinatorical meaning of $x$ is.

Can anyone offer any insight, or pointers to work that examines this question?